# Graphql: How can I solve the N + N problem?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

After having implemented dataloader in the respective resolvers to solve the N+1 problem, I also need to be able to solve the N+N problem.

I need a decently efficient data loading mechanism to get a relation like this:

```
{
  persons (active: true) {
    id,
    given_name,
    projects (active: true) {
      id,
      title,
    }
  }
}
```

I've created a naive implementation for this, returning

```
{
  persons: [
    {
      id: 1,
      given_name: 'Mike'
      projects: [
        { 
          id: 1,
          title: 'API'
        },
        { 
          id: 2,
          title: 'Frontend'
        }      
      ]
    } 
    {
      id: 2,
      given_name: 'Eddie'
      projects: [
        { 
          id: 2,
          title: 'Frontend'
        },      
        { 
          id: 3,
          title: 'Testing'
        }
      ]
    } 
  ]
}
```

In SQL the underlying structure would be represented by a many many to many relationship.

Is there a similiar tool like dataloader for solving this or can this maybe even be solved with dataloader itself?

Answer (score 1):

The expectation with GraphQL is that the trip to the database is generally the fastest thing you can do, so you just add a resolver to Person.projects that makes a call to the database. You can still use dataLoaders for that.

```js
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    persons(parent, args, context) {
      // 1st call to database
      return someUsersService.list()
    },
  },
  Person: {
    projects(parent, args, context) {
      // this should be a dataLoader behind the scenes.
      // Makes second call to database
      return projectsService.loadByUserId(parent.id)
    }
  }
}
```

Just remember that now your dataLoader is expecting to return an Array of objects in each slot instead of a single object.

Comment: But in my case the result of persons is the root (parent) of projects. Instead of parent being a single person the result is a collection of persons. Thus in the projects resolver you would need to process someProjectsDataLoaderByPersonId.load(parent.map(parentItem => parentItem.id)).

I think your const __resolvers__ should be renamed to __schema__.

Comment: No. In Person.projects, the parent is _one instance_ of the array that is returned in the `persons` call. This is why you use a dataloader: so that with the whole array of `person.projects` calls that are made, you use one dataLoader to make a single database call.

Also: why would I name my resolvers "schema"? "Schema" is the GraphQL SDL string.

Comment: As I understand – correct me, if I am wrong – the data loader someUsersDataLoader.load(args.id) would only query for a single user. Hence args.id, is that right?  But the persons-resolver needs to be able to query multiple users i.e. user ids. I hope I understood your intentions. Regarding the schema: I don't use SDL and I misunderstood (a lot anyway) your resolvers as code schema. Don't know why.

Comment: That's how you call dataLoaders, but not how they work. You call `someUsersDataLoader.load(id)` in a ton of places, and you define the dataLoader as `(ids => { doSomeBatchLoadCall(ids); return ids.map(findInResult) }`. This means that you make 100 calls to the dataloader, which makes one call to the database and returns to each call its result.

Comment: I updated the code above to reflect this a bit better.

Comment: My bad, you're absolutely right. Thanks for your explanantion and patience.